# Singleton dealloc is never called

Tags: objective-c, macos, singleton

My program starts and exists w/o triggering dealloc.

```
@interface Printer : NSObject
+ (instancetype)instance;
-(void)print;
@end

@implementation Printer

+ (instancetype)instance {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
-(void) print {
    printf(@"Printer printing...\n");
}
-(void)dealloc {
    printf(@"Printer dealloc\n");
}
@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Printer* tmp = [Printer instance];
    [tmp print];
}
```

I am getting the following output:

```
Printer printing...
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

according to the output, `dealloc` is never called. breakpoint inside dealloc is never triggered even whenever my console app is triggered.

Any ideas what is wrong? 
I believe its due to the `static` `sharedInstance` variable, however, not sure what to do about it.

Comment: Singletons are never destroyed. Allocate and release memory dynamically if you wish destructors to work.

Comment: This is not answering my question. Singletons don't need to be proactively destroyed and this is clear to me. However, they should be destroyed at some point, i assume to be the problem exist sequence.

Comment: No they are never released. There is no code that does that. OS simply marks app memory as free when your app finishes execution.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. What if there are network connections opened by this singleton? files have been opened? dynamically allocated memory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objects Held Until App End: No Dealloc is okay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010701/objects-held-until-app-end-no-dealloc-is-okay)